# Getting facebook page information using Flash Application

Tags: facebook, json, web-services, actionscript-3

How do I get information from a Facebook page (eg About, id, first name last name etc) through an app that im making in Adobe Flash (ActionScript 3).

I've done this so far:

```
var request:URL Request = new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/362134400532769?fields=id,name");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLloader();
loader.load(request);
```

Is that right?

If so, I'm guessing it would return an array of all the elements. How do you then go about attracting the element?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you then go about attracting the element?

Use the following process:

- Loop through the array
- Check the type of the element at each index
- If it matches the type you need, use it
- Otherwise, skip it